# Why $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}=s \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{s-a_k}-n$ where is $s=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

> Why
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}=s \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{s-a_k}-n$$ where is $s=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$?

but not
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k} \neq s \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{s-a_k}$$
Similar contradiction

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s-a_k}{a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{s}{a_k}-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{a_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n 1=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}-n-\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \neq s \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}-2 n$$
The correct answer is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s-a_k}{a_k}=s \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}-n$$

It would also be great if someone recommends books on this topic or individual chapters in books. Summation is a topic that is poorly covered in analysis.

Comment: [Your two first equalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4782480/1) (at least), [now deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4782480/2), were wrong. $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\ne\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k=\sum_{j=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k=n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k.$ And $n\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k\ne \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sum_{k=1}^nb_k=s\sum_{k=1}^nb_k.$

Comment: The problem with your tries is that a formula like $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n$ makes no sense. You cannot have a repeated summation index. If you were to substitute the expression for $s$ into the summation you would have to use a different letter for the summation variable, e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^n s = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_j$ would be correct. This is a common error with double summations you have to be careful with. That said you do not need any information about what $s$ is to solve the problem here - the identity holds for any $s$ so just treat it as a free variable.

Comment: Actually it does make sense, but not what you intended: $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ means $\sum_{k=1}^nt$ (i.e. $nt$), where $t=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k.$ Equivalently (as first commented) $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ means $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given identity is equivalent to
$$s\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{s-a_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}=n.$$
Then the left-hand side is equal to
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{s-a_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{s}{s-a_k}- \frac{a_k}{s-a_k}\right)=
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s-a_k}{s-a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n$$
and we are done.

In a similar way
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s-a_k}{a_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{a_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{a_k}=s\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}-n.$$

In both cases we applied the linearity property of summation (see the first two identities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities)):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\alpha a_k+\beta b_k)=\alpha\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k+\beta \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k.$$

Answer (score 2):

[Your two first equalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4782480/1) (at least), [now deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4782480/2), were wrong. $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\ne\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k=\sum_{j=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k=n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k.$ And $n\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k\ne \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sum_{k=1}^nb_k=s\sum_{k=1}^nb_k.$

Your two examples can be justified simultaneously:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{y_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{x_k+y_k}{y_k}-1\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k+y_k}{y_k}\right)-n.$$
This can be applied to $(x_k,y_k)=(a_k,s-a_k)$ as well as to $(x_k,y_k)=(s-a_k,a_k).$ In both cases, $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k+y_k}{y_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac s{y_k}=s\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{y_k}.$

Answer (score 1):

A small variation and a hint. Since $a_k=s-\left(s-a_k\right)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{s-a_k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s-\left(s-a_k\right)}{s-a_k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s}{s-a_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s-a_k}{s-a_k}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s}{s-a_k}-n}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows. Note that here we can do the transformations without using detailed information about $s$.

**Hint:** You might find Chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/concrete-mathematics-a-foundation-for-computer-science)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik useful.
It provides a thorough introduction to the use of sums.